# How to select a video codec when capturing with DSPack?

Tags: delphi, video, delphi-2010, dspack

I need to create an application that captures a video from a webcam. Later on I need to load the video and be able to navigate around in the video freely.

When I use the videocap-demo that comes with the Sources of DSPack, the captured video is encoded in H264. When I navigate around in that video, the picture becomes blurry, with wrong colors and you can't recognize the picture. (I tried with VLC and Windows media player)

[image: Before navigation]

...playing the video works, but after jumping to any position in the video, it looks like this...

[image: After navigation]

How can I tell DSPack to capture the video e.g. in the old MJPEG-format?
(I tried with old videos from my camera. In MJpeg the navigation seems to work flawless)

Thanks in advance, R.

Comment: The problem you are encountering isn't so much in the codec with which the video was encoded but in the software that you use to play that video. Now in order to understand why this is happening you need to know some basics about video compression. You see when a video is compressed some of the pictures that represents some frames are removed and replaced by special data packets which instead containing whole picture only contains information that tells video decoder which parts of previous frame/picture were changed and how. ...

Comment: ... Now while replacing all but first frame images would lead to best compression but it would also lead to scenario where a small data corruption could screw up the entire video since you always need previous frame in order to make suitable changes to it. This is why almost all compressed videos contain these so called key frames which are video frames that include uncompressed image. Most often these key frames occur at fixed intervals but not always. Some video codecs are also capable of inserting additional key frames when necessary (big change in the picture) ...

Comment: .. So why are you getting corrupted image when playing your video? That is because when VLC or WMP jump to a frame which does not contain entire picture (key frame) but only information about changes made to previous frame they apply those changes to the frame from which you jumped off. This results in this corrupted image you encounter. I bet that if you wait long enough for video playback to reach next key frame the video image will fix itself. ...

Comment: ... So how should video playing software work to avoid this issues? First it should not directly jump to non key frames which I'm kid of curious as of why your VLC player allows you to do so. I remember that old VLC player was always jumping only to nearest key frame and newer in between in order to avoid these problems. Another approach that many video playback programs use is to jump to the first previous key frame of the desired frame you are jumping to and then fast play (without rendering) to the frame you are jumping to. ...

Comment: ... This way all the changes of individual frames that come after that key frame are applied correctly so there is no  image corruption. One program that I know is capable of doing so is BS Player with combination of official DivX codecs (video playback setup that I use). So before changing the encoding codec you might want to make sure that the problem is not in your video playback software  in the first place. Also note that changing the encoding video codec might not solve your problem. It might make it less apparent because different codecs use different key frame intervals. ...

Comment: ... In fact I would recommend you that you first check the demo source code to see what parameters it is passing to codec and try fiddling with them to see if they affect the end results. Sorry for bunch of comments but I don't know how to write this in shorter version while keeping it understandable enough.

Comment: If you want to use MJPEG you need an MJPEG encoder. The last time I looked Windows (XP) didn't have one included (Only a decoder). So the first thing to check is whether you even have one installed. (I'm away from my computer right now, so I can't look up how to configure DSPack for using it. It can be done though, because I have done it.